Embedding SQL in Mulesoft Process Layer? Architecture advice
I know Mulesoft advocates that internal systems should be wrapped into a "System" layer application, and that the executing logic should be put inside a "Process" layer. Usually I agree, System layers allows communication toward the internal systems to change. It's like writing a interface around your Repository class.
However I'm in a performance critical scenario. I'm not speaking time wise (the extra layer just cost around a brunch of milliseconds). I'm speaking of an application that keeps consuming data from RabbitMQ and write/read to SQL on each message. It is designed to stay at high CPU usage for most of the day with the highest number possible of thread listeners.
Actually the small read and write operations within the standard JDBC driver use less CPU than HTTP requests (or at least seems to do so in a quick artificial test I did), enough to add 4/5 extra listeners and stay within good CPU usage. So embedding SQL in my application will actually improve throughput, probably also cutting running costs (less cores needed).
Any good reason to keep SQL on a separate application?
Assume of course I do already proper connection pooling.
